# pandas group by agg select within group according to pattern

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to write a custom aggregation function that will always choose the string ending with the fewest zeros from within each group. For instance, here is an example dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"group" : [1, 1, 1, 2, 2], "value" : ["10534", "30400", "30400", "34355", "35000"]})
```

My goal here is to return something like this:

```
group  value
1      "10534"
1      "10534"
1      "10534"
2      "34355"
2      "34355"
```

Using `groupby` because the problem is in actuality much larger.

My custom aggregation function works on its own but will not return the intended result when included in a `.groupby().agg()` formulation:

```
def collapse_concatenated_ids(x, varname):
    ids = x[varname]
    ids = ids.reset_index(drop = True)
    ids = ids.astype(str)
    N = len(ids[0])

    for j in range(0, N):
        for i in ids:
            if i[N-j-1] != "0":
                return i
    return ids[0]

collapse_concatenated_ids(dupe, 'msg_id')
```

There's something not clicking for me about aggregation in python. Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, I would use pandas vectorized string operations to find out the number of trailing zeros, e.g. by string length difference after removing these zeros:

```
>>> nzeros = df['value'].str.len() - df['value'].str.rstrip('0').str.len()
>>> nzeros
0    0
1    2
2    2
3    0
4    3
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

Alternately you could use regular expression matching:

```
>>> df['value'].str.extract('(0*$)')[0].str.len()
0    0
1    2
2    2
3    0
4    3
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

Now we can simply find the min zeros count per group, or better yet the index of rows with min zeros counts per group, using `idxmin`:

```
>>> nzeros.groupby(df['group']).idxmin()
group
1    0
2    3
Name: value, dtype: int64
>>> df.loc[nzeros.groupby(df['group']).idxmin()]
   group  value
0      1  10534
3      2  34355
```

To maintain the size, we need `groupby.transform()`, but how we use `idxmin` then changes a little. Here’s what I can think of without lambda:

```
>>> nzeros.groupby(df['group']).transform('idxmin').map(df['value'])
0    10534
1    10534
2    10534
3    34355
4    34355
Name: value, dtype: object
```

Comment: Cimbali sorry, your answer is excellent, but I just realized I slightly mis-asked the question. I just changed the desired output to preserve the total number of rows, but overwrite those within groups.